# Wordpress, how to fetch all Custom Posts with meta data

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I need to fetch all posts of specific type (Custom post type)
But I need this object to include all of the Meta of this post.
Right now I am using a loop for it, but it's request intensive IMHO.

Is there another way?

```
    $arrVendorGetPostRequest = array(        
        'post_type'        => 'vendor',
        'suppress_filters' => 0,
        'numberposts'      => -1,
        'tax_query'        => [
          [
            'taxonomy'         => $taxonomy,
            'field'            => 'id',
            'terms'            => (array)$term_id,
            'include_children' => false
          ]
        ]
    );

$vendors          = get_posts($arrVendorGetPostRequest);
$vendorsFull = array();
$ratingKey = $review->slug . '_rating';

foreach ($vendors as $key => $vendor) {
    $meta = get_post_meta($vendor->ID);
}
```

Comment: You can use database query directly and use JOIN of post and post_meta table.

Comment: You have an example?

Comment: You'd probably be better off keeping your code as is and just using some caching.

Comment: Use wp_post ,wp_postmeta and wp_termmeta table to solve your problem.

Comment: @Jrod caching with transient will only increase the wp-options, external caching will need to be invalidated on save... I am looking for more internal solution.

Comment: You will need to use a subquery for every meta value you want to retrieve back. You can use the global  `$wpdb` to access the `wpdb` class and perform a custom query with SQL using `$wpdb->get_results()`. Alternatively you could use the `posts_fields` filter to add your subqueries to the query. Then you would add this filter before your call to `get_posts` and then remove it right after so you don't affect other queries.